# Can't execute server command from client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to spawn a bullet when player hit screen. When I make server in matchmaking I can spawn bullets and I can see them on client side too. But when I connect like client to server on matchmaking I can't spawn bullets. I got this error on server side:

> Found no behaviour for incoming [Command:InvokeCmdCmd_Fire] on Player(Clone) >(UnityEngine.GameObject), the server and client should have the same NetworkBehaviour instances [netId=2].
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

My code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Input.touchCount; x++) 
        {
            touchpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch[x].position);
            if ((touchpos.x > -4.5f || touchpos.y > -1.2f))
            {
               pos = transform.position;

               if (magazine > 0)
                {
                    if (time > firetime && autoriffle)
                    {
                        Cmd_Fire();

                        time = 0;
                        magazine--;

                    }

        time += Time.deltaTime;

    }

    [Command]
    void Cmd_Fire()
    {      
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulet, pos, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, new Vector3(touchpos.x, touchpos.y, transform.position.z) - transform.position)) as GameObject;

        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(bullet.transform.up * bulletspeed, ForceMode.Impulse);

        NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);

        // I try NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(bullet, connectionToClient); too but same reason
    }
```

I have this script on my player prefab. I have add on player and on bullet prefab Network Identity and Network Transform. On player I checked Local Player Authority.

I also tried to make a new project where I put everything from the official Unity Multiplayer Networking tutorial but it didn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was destroying this script if it wasn't attached to local player. I should only do-

```
if(!isLocalPlayer)
   return;`
```

not

```
if(!isLocalPlayer)
{
   Destroy(this);
   return;
}
```